# Remove outer indexes from JSON string Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string in JavaScript:

```
{
 "0":
   {"race":"Race1","sum":"13.7","color":"#BEBEBE"},
 "1":
   {"race":"Race2","sum":"20.3","color":"#B03060"},
 "2":
   {"race":"Race3","sum":"35.2","color":"#FFFF01"},
 "3":
   {"race":"Race4","sum":"31.3","color":"#4A6FE3"},
 "4":
   {"race":"Unknown","sum":0,"color":"#9ACD32"}
}
```

Which i need to convert into:

> Edited example

```
[{"race":"Race1","sum":"13.7","color":"#BEBEBE"},
  {"race":"Race2","sum":"20.3","color":"#B03060"},
  {"race":"Race3","sum":"35.2","color":"#FFFF01"},
  {"race":"Race4","sum":"31.3","color":"#4A6FE3"},
  {"race":"Unknown","sum":0,"color":"#9ACD32"}]
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Fixed it. now it is parsing

Comment: It'd be nice to see your effort.

Comment: i am new to this so had no idea how to remove indexes

Comment: I would recommend in your next question, that you do some quick reading on the problem, and then post your efforts along with the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have object within an object without keys, you should be hanving them within the arrays or as it is in original state

If your want to modify, make use `Object.key(obj)` and then loop over all the keys

```js
var obj = {
 "0":
   {"race":"Race1","sum":"13.7","color":"#BEBEBE"},
 "1":
   {"race":"Race2","sum":"20.3","color":"#B03060"},
 "2":
   {"race":"Race3","sum":"35.2","color":"#FFFF01"},
 "3":
   {"race":"Race4","sum":"31.3","color":"#4A6FE3"},
 "4":
   {"race":"Unknown","sum":0,"color":"#9ACD32"}
}

var arr = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item) {
  arr.push(obj[item]);
})

console.log(arr);
```

Or use map as @trincot also suggested

```js
var obj = {
 "0":
   {"race":"Race1","sum":"13.7","color":"#BEBEBE"},
 "1":
   {"race":"Race2","sum":"20.3","color":"#B03060"},
 "2":
   {"race":"Race3","sum":"35.2","color":"#FFFF01"},
 "3":
   {"race":"Race4","sum":"31.3","color":"#4A6FE3"},
 "4":
   {"race":"Unknown","sum":0,"color":"#9ACD32"}
}


var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(item) {
  return obj[item]
})

console.log(arr);
```

However the simplestwould to use `Object.values(obj)`

```js
var obj = {
 "0":
   {"race":"Race1","sum":"13.7","color":"#BEBEBE"},
 "1":
   {"race":"Race2","sum":"20.3","color":"#B03060"},
 "2":
   {"race":"Race3","sum":"35.2","color":"#FFFF01"},
 "3":
   {"race":"Race4","sum":"31.3","color":"#4A6FE3"},
 "4":
   {"race":"Unknown","sum":0,"color":"#9ACD32"}
}




console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: Maybe use `map` with `return` instead of `forEach` with `push`: will be more functional.

Comment: ES**whatever** `Object.values(obj)` Works in Chrome :)

Comment: yes @trincot, i.e another approach I was about to add in my answer

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, I remembered it late, but added that to the answer as well

Answer (score 3):

You can simply parse and get the values like this..

```js
var jsonStr = '{"0":{"race":"Race1","sum":"13.7","color":"#BEBEBE"},"1":{"race":"Race2","sum":"20.3","color":"#B03060"},"2":{"race":"Race3","sum":"35.2","color":"#FFFF01"},"3":{"race":"Race4","sum":"31.3","color":"#4A6FE3"},"4":{"race":"Unknown","sum":0,"color":"#9ACD32"}}';

var json = Object.values(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
console.log(json)
```

Comment: thanks @Burak. This also works and following also works so vote up

Answer (score 0):

Use the `object.values()` function:

```
let f= 
{
 "0":
   {"race":"Race1","sum":"13.7","color":"#BEBEBE"},
 "1":
   {"race":"Race2","sum":"20.3","color":"#B03060"},
 "2":
   {"race":"Race3","sum":"35.2","color":"#FFFF01"},
 "3":
   {"race":"Race4","sum":"31.3","color":"#4A6FE3"},
 "4":
   {"race":"Unknown","sum":0,"color":"#9ACD32"}
}
```

Output of `Console.log(Object.values(f))`:

```
[ { race: 'Race1', sum: '13.7', color: '#BEBEBE' },
  { race: 'Race2', sum: '20.3', color: '#B03060' },
  { race: 'Race3', sum: '35.2', color: '#FFFF01' },
  { race: 'Race4', sum: '31.3', color: '#4A6FE3' },
  { race: 'Unknown', sum: 0, color: '#9ACD32' } ]
```